# "Как пить дать" - разные значения

Tags: фразеология

Меня интересует выражение "как пить дать". С одной стороны (и об этом нам говорит словарь фразеологизмов), это выражение означает "легко, быстро". Но чаще его можно услышать, скорее, в значении "это уж точно": *"Плохи они, слов нет, и с кадетами они нас опять сосватают, как пить дать"* (М. Шолохов).
Так все-таки, каково точное значение фразеологизма и еще интересно было бы узнать его происхождение. При чем тут, собственно, подача воды?

[image]

Comment: Визуально очень  доходчивый вопрос! Почему струйка слабая? Фильтр на выходе надо почистить, и Кот, как пить дать, человеческим языком скажет: "Спасибо!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это словарь Яндекс.ру даёт толкование:Какъ пить дать (иноск.) — сдѣлать навѣрное, скоро.
Ср. Небывалаго, вотъ хоть тебя къ примѣру взять, оплетутъ, какъ пить дать — мигнуть не успѣешь.
Мельниковъ. Въ лѣсахъ. 3, 2.
Ср.           ...Тебя ужъ упекутъ
Подъ судъ — какъ пить дадутъ.
Не слушаю — подъ судъ, подъ судъ!
Грибоѣдовъ. Горе отъ ума. 2, 3. Фамусовъ.
Ср. Жаждалъ, и вы напоили Меня.
Матѳ. 25, 35.

А крылатое это выражение - афоризм из романа И.Лажечникова (1838 г.) «Басурман». Один из действующих героев этого романа – иноземец-лекарь Антон. О нем поговаривали, что он не столько лекарь, сколько отравитель. «Раз вздумал один здешний барин, старичок, полечиться у него, – говорит один из героев романа другому, – как пить дал, отправил на тот свет. Да и мальчик, баронский слуга, которого он любил как сына, лишь приложился к губам мертвого, чтобы проститься... тут же испустил дух. Так сильно было зелье, которое Антон дал покойнику». Это выражение неожиданно прижилось и по своему влиянию на современников может быть приравнено к современным присказкам, типа «Ерш твою медь» или «Ёлы-палы»… Но если в контексте «Басурмана» «как пить дать» вполне гармонирует хотя бы с профессией героя, который давал пить лекарство своим пациентам, то смысл выражения в последующие годы и десятилетия несколько изменился. Теперь мы приравниваем это выражение к таким, как «вне всяких сомнений», «хотим мы того или нет» или, скажем, «без всяких преувеличений».  Большинству наших современников фамилия «Лажечников» практически ничего не говорит, но «как пить дать» они знают и даже иногда применяют в своей речи уже как поговорку в значении "непременно, точно".

( http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-9255/ )

Другие словари объясняют современное употребление:По обычаю древних славян, никто не имел права отказать человеку в воде. С тех пор и пошло выражение как пить дать в значении «точно», «несомненно». http://frazbook.ru/2008/10/22/kak-pit-dat/

Толковый словарь Д. Н. Ушакова, 1935-1940, совмещает значения: Значение - наверняка, непременно, наверное . Выражение от старинной традиции давать путникам напиться. Дать путнику воды - простое и не затратное дело, поэтому выражение употреблялось в таком значении.

Answer (score 4):

Рассмотрев все примеры Нацкорпуса по 19 столетию, можно сделать вывод. Вначале смысл был : легко, не напрягаясь. Что может быть легче, чем подать человеку кружку воды? Потом акцент начал смещаться в сторону непременности события. Но фактически оба смысла взаимозаменяемы в достаточно большой степени :
*он легко выиграет*... *он обязательно выиграет*... 
[Нацкорпус](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_created&out=normal&kwsz=5&dpp=10&spd=10&seed=&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&text=lexform&mode=main&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EA%E0%EA+%EF%E8%F2%FC+%E4%E0%E4%F3%F2)

Answer (score 2):

А не могли бы Вы дать ссылку на этот словарь, который дает "легко, быстро"? Никогда не слышал. Конечно, эта идиома означает "непременно, точно".